# TensorFlow how to safely terminate training manually (KeyboardInterrupt)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I wish to add functionality to my code such that if I desire to terminate the code at any point it will safely terminate training and save the variables. Although I've tried searching for a better solution, I think catching a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception would be my best bet.

Would it, however, be safe? More specifically, would the following code work:

```
with tf.Session() as sess    
    try:
        for i in range(FLAGS.max_steps):
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=some_feed_dictionary)
            # Some other summary writing and evaluative operations
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Manual interrupt occurred.")

    print('Done training for {} steps'.format(global_steps))
    save_path = saver.save(sess, 'Standard CNN', global_step=global_steps, write_meta_graph=False)
```

Or is it unsafe and can result in corrupted save files considering the Keyboard Interrupt is free to occur in the middle of any tensorflow operation? Is there an adequate way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use something very similar to this by catching `KeyboardInterrupt` during training all the time, the only difference is I "save" after each `sess.run` step (or every several of those steps), never had problems with that.

I do not know the answer to "is it unsafe" but I know that my method worked to avoid even asking that question...

In your code that would look like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess    
    try:
        for i in range(FLAGS.max_steps):
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=some_feed_dictionary)
            # Some other summary writing and evaluative operations
            if i % save_steps == 0:
                save_path = saver.save(sess, 'Standard CNN', global_step=global_steps, write_meta_graph=False)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Manual interrupt occurred.")
        print('Done training for {} steps'.format(global_steps))
```

To clarify, the `save_steps` variable determines how many steps between saves.